# SET keyword in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query

I have been using SET keyword to assign the values to parameters declared in SQL Server something like,

```
Declare @StudentName Nvarchar(max) 
SET @StudentName='ABC'
```

I'm not sure how to write this if they are more than 1 student name.

Say student names are being fetched from another Select Statement (Select student_name from student_tbl)

Will that be

```
SET @StudentName= 'Select student_name from student_tbl'
```

I'm not sure how SET works in case of multiple values.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you plan to do with `@StudentName` once it has been assigned a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple values shouldn't be assigned to a scalar variable. It makes no sense

You need a table variable (or temporary table).

```
Declare @StudentName TABLE (sname Nvarchar(max));
INSERT @StudentName (sname) VALUES ('ABC'),('DEF'),('PQR'),('XYZ');
```

You can JOIN etc to this as you would a normal table. Or use it in an IN clause

```
WHERE
    X.SomeCol IN (SELECT sname FROM @StudentName)
```

Edit, after comments

```
INSERT @StudentName (sname) 
SELECT ... -- the other query here
```

Comment: Gbn: What if the values that are assigned to SET, can be fetched by another select statement

Comment: @Xorpower: please update your question then with more examples.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please post another answer as this script might be useful some day. Thanks

Comment: @Xorpower: I've already edited. A set of rows goes into a table (whatever type), not a scalar variable

Comment: Gbn: I did the same thing. but the SQL Query is not able to find the parameter name

Comment: @Xorpower: I have no idea what you mean now

Comment: @Xorpower - If you are trying to use a table variable in a join you need to give it an alias or reference it with square brackets to avoid the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@Foo"`. Is that what you mean? e.g. use `DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT); SELECT * FROM sys.objects o JOIN @T ON [@T].X = o.object_id`